# How to explicitly call a conversion function whose conversion-type-id contains a placeholder specifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct A{
  operator auto(){
     return 0;
  }
};
int main(){
   A a;
   a.operator auto(); // #1
   a.operator int(); //  #2
}
```

[GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/3jdaK9) accepts that #2 is the right way to call the conversion function explicitly while [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Ehf5vG) accepts #1.

It seems that `#1` is ill-formed due to the following rule:
[dcl.spec.auto#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#6)

> A program that uses auto or decltype(auto) in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.

This usage `a.operator auto()` is not explicitly allowed in section [dcl.spec.auto], hence it should be ill-formed. However, for the second usage, which is accepted by GCC, the standard does not say that the `conversion-function-id` where the `conversion-type-id` is **replaced by the deduced type** denotes the name of the conversion function. In other words, the declared `conversion-function-id` in the declaration is `operator auto` rather than `operator int`. The former has the same token as the declarator-id of the declaration. According to the grammar, the unqualified-id `operator auto` should be the name of that conversion function. So, how to explicitly call this conversion function? Is it underspecified in the standard about which is the name of the conversion function when it contains a placeholder specifier?

Comment: While a conversion operator *can* be called directly, the *preferred* approach is to simply assign the object to a variable of the desired type, eg: `A a; int i = a;`, or at least use `static_cast` to invoke the operator with the desired type, eg: `A a; static_cast<int>(a);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Those have quite different behavior if used in template code where `A` could be any type such as `double`.  OP's code would refuse to compile, whereas yours would truncate the double.  And in my mind, template code is the only place where this question really matters (otherwise why use `operator auto`?).

Comment: @JohnZwinck The thing about templates is that they can be constrained. This kind of code could be inside a template that only allows class/struct types, for instance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that usage. The question here is tagged with [language-lawyer], hence we don't care how to use it in a suggested way. We only care how the code could be ill-formed by the relevant rule. BTW, the standard does not forbid us to use the function name to call the function explicitly.

Comment: Data point: MSVC likes "auto".

Comment: @DavidBien In my mind, MSVC is not reliable. Anyhow, it‘s a proponent.

Comment: Lol. If you like to be able to actually debug your code, MSVC is very reliable... gdb can't even find any code at all for about half of my templates... Anyway just offered as a data point. I've been dealing with them since I converted my codebase from clang/gcc to msvc and they are very responsive wrt to compiler bugs, etc. They definitely are quite familiar with the Standard.

Comment: @DavidBien Yeah, I mean that gcc and clang are more familiar with the Standard.

Comment: It makes sense for genericity's sake for auto to be used, otherwise you'd need to know the type of the thing you were accessing, which negates the helpfulness of auto whatsoever... However I could also see the usefulness of allowing both - since compilation should then fail if you accessed a non-deduced type conversion. I.e. I would like the compilation to succeed in both of your examples but to fail it I specified a.operator double().

Comment: @DavidBien As I said in the question, if I understand the rule correctly, `a.operator auto()` is not a valid usage as per [dcl.spec.auto#6], whereas, I don't have idea for `a.operator int()`.

Comment: I gotcha and I agree. I was merely saying what would “seem to be reasonable” in this case irrespective of the current verbiage of the standard.

Comment: If you modify the #1 to read `std::cout << typeid(a.operator auto()).name() << std::endl`, you are getting "int" as the type. Which means that clang walks up the deduction up to `0` in `return 0`.

Comment: If you remove the definition of the operator's method (but not the declaration), then CLang complains it can't use the method until it's defined, but GCC does not even consider it.

Comment: @xryl669 The key point here is what is the name of the conversion function? Is it the literal conversion-function-id or the synthesized conversion-function-id by replacing the placeholder specifier with the deduced type?

Comment: Great question! In order to emphasize, that Clang - whether standard compliant here or not - is a bit more self-consistent, one can add `operator int()` to the struct. Gcc should refuse that definition already if it solely uses auto here for deduction and not for an explicit function naming context, but it doesn't.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3903.html#FI4 a bit emphasizes, that operator auto is a bit special here and might not be that deeply specified as one might hope it is. Seen from the aspect, that only one auto operator per class is allowed and that it can fully stand in parallel to existing explicit ones that are effectively the same, it must be explicitly referrable, at latest within a template context. So clang is again more consistent here, while with gcc you can have compileable but never usable classes in doubt since the ambiguities cannot be resolved explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

It seems, that this is not specified precisely enough.

1. From `10.1.7.4 The auto specifier`:

> The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the
> decl-specifier-seq, type-specifier-seq, **conversion-function-id**, or
> trailing-return-type, in any context where such a declarator is valid.

Reading precisely, one might distinguish here between "can" and the stronger "can only", i.e. potentially opening up room for degrees of freedom for compiler intrinsics (strictly wrong vs. unspecified behavior).

And `3.4.5 class member access` says:

> 7 If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its
> conversion-type-id is first looked up in the class of the object
> expression and the name, if found, is used.

Again leaving room for interpretation if the auto keyword can effectively be a fully qualified conversion-type-id within this context or not.

Your question itself might have to be further branched, namely

1. What are the overloading rules for the operator auto() usage in detail, i.e. should it be available for regular candidates competition already on class definition level? (not the case for Clang and Gcc, both accept the operator a priori besides an extra operator int() ...)
2. Can the operator auto() be called with explicit member operator referring (your case 1), i.e. effectively, has it a (unique) accessible name? Allowing that would be contradictory to all other explicitly allowed use cases for the keyword.

I've seen explicit tests for this within several clang revisions so its behavior is not an artefact of implicit naming convention applicance but an explicitly desired behavior obviously.

As already mentioned within the comments, Clang's behavior is a bit more overall consistent here at least in comparison to gcc since it's totally clear there, where the auto keyword is used for type deduction and where for name / function-id resolution. The operator auto() there is handled as a more explicit own entity, whereas for gcc, it has anonymous character similar to a lambda but is involved within candidates competition even for the explicit member operator access way.

Comment: As I said in my question, the standard mentions "A program that uses auto or decltype(auto) in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed." That is, `a.operator auto()` where `auto` is not explicitly allowed in section [dcl.spec.auto]

Comment: Yes, you're right in terms of auto as a type placeholder, I totally missed this part when writing the answer... But.since section 10.1.7.4. is only about this quality of auto, one might be extremely quirky in saying, that the phrases about conversion-type-ids could allow an exception here, but still not really convincing I admit. A full clarification here requires a deeper clarification first about the question how operator auto() participates in overload resolution and if it's conversion-type-id is always the deduced type.

Comment: If the deduced type fully determines the conversion-type-ids,then there would not be that much room for speculation and gcc would be totally correct.But since there's only one operator auto() allowed per class/struct (as per standard!) and since it can a priori exist parallely to an operator definition that has the same ret-type as the deduced operator auto in class definition (as per standard?), all follow-up speculation might be futile since there's too much inconsistency persistent here.The standard must first precisley specify operator auto() itself, that I don't see for the current state.

Comment: "But since there's only one operator auto() allowed per class/struct (as per standard!)" Agree with it as per [dcl.spec.auto#12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#12). Hence, `operator auto()` should be the unique name of the conversion function in its enclosing class. I now prefer to consider it as a defect of the standard.

Comment: Me too. Unfortunately, I didn't found any related public discussions or defect reports about this issue, only some about the operator-template case and some recommendations to ban this operator totally from the language...

Comment: If there's no excellent way to solve the defect, I would prefer to see that `operator auto()` will be banned. Maybe we could first try to post a defect report regarding this question(Unfortunately, I don't know where to post).

Comment: https://isocpp.org/std/submit-issue could be a starting point. I've never done it myself before though.