# What is correct syntax for explicit call to conversion operator with deduced return type (auto)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

We encountered a curious inconsistency between language implementations in the question [What is operator auto in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68266659/2079303).

There, conversion operator with deduced return type (auto) is called explicitly. But it appears that compilers don't agree whether it should be called using `auto` or the deduced type [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/5YeEh68TM) [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/rK3doEq7d):

```
struct A
{
  operator auto() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   a.operator auto(); // Clang and MSVC: OK,    GCC: ERROR
   a.operator int();  // Clang and MSVC: ERROR, GCC: OK
}
```

Which language implementation is correct? Is this under-specified in the standard?

Comment: Personally, I suspect GCC has it. The deduced type must be concrete because you could have several `operator auto()` functions in one class. How else would you differentiate them?

Comment: GCC implementation feels more correct. That auto is placeholder indicating deduced return type but standard is not saying that the placeholder may be used in call site as well. Also it can't identify an operator uniquely.

Comment: @eerorika Yes you are correct, you can't have more than one. But as a possible future improvement, falling on the GGC side may be the way to go.

Comment: Msvc follows clangs [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rWhjc48oE).

Comment: You know what, forget my answer. I think it warrants a defect. Though GCC is still the one where my money is.

Comment: dup of [How to explicitly call a conversion function whose conversion-type-id contains a placeholder specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66485833/how-to-explicitly-call-a-conversion-function-whose-conversion-type-id-contains-a)